# Enable/Disable button using dynamically added checkbox's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am working on a simple to-do list.  Currently I have three buttons(enterBtn, completeBtn, deleteBtn)-all disabled on startup.  The first one EnterBtn, gets enabled when the form is complete using jquery(works fine).  Then when i submit form, javascript creates a < ul > that contains a span and a checkbox(also works fine).  Now, I want to enable the completeBtn if/when any of the NEW checkbox items are checked.  Can someone help me figure out how to toggle my complete button?  The culmination is to use completeBtn to both enable when any checkboxes are clicked, and then i am planning on removing only the ones that where checked, but i'll get to that part on my own.  The only help i need is to figure out the best way to go about this based on my code below.

I will //comment in spots where I've tested so far.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="goalId">
<input id="completeBtn" value="Complete" type="button"   disabled="disabled"/>
<ul id="log_data"></ul>
```

JavaScript

```
function disableFunction() {
document.getElementById("enterBtn").disabled = 'true';
}
function enableFunction(cbId) {
//tested here
}
function checkSpanStatus() {
alert("path works");
} 
function updateItemStatus() {
var cbId = this.Id.replace("cb_","");
var itemText = document.getElementById("item_" + cbId);
if(this.checked) {
itemText.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
//document.getElementById("completeBtn").disabled = 'false'; <tried this>
enableFunction(); //and this
}else{
itemText.style.textDecoration = "none";
}
}

function addNewItem(list, itemText) {
totalItems++;

var listItem = document.createElement("ul");


var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
checkbox.type = "checkbox";
checkbox.Id =  "cb_" + totalItems;
checkbox.onclick = updateItemStatus;

var span = document.createElement("span");
span.id = "item_" + totalItems;
span.onclick = checkSpanStatus;
span.innerText = itemText;
listItem.appendChild(span);
listItem.appendChild(checkbox);
list.appendChild(listItem);
}
var totalItems = 0;
var inItemText = document.getElementById("goalId");
var form = document.getElementById("goalForm");
function btn1() {{
var itemText = inItemText.value;
if (!itemText || itemText == " ") {
return false
};
addNewItem(document.getElementById("log_data"), itemText);
form.reset();
disableFunction();
}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you can't disable buttons is that you should use `boolean` instead of `string`:

```
your_button.disabled = true;
your_button.disabled = false;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philip100/bjmomda7/) (using your script)

Comment: Thank You Phillip.  i should have just done that to begin with.  Here i am trying to be all fancy.  I can deduce what you did with the JS fiddle, that was very helpful.

Comment: wow you did alot. I wish i had the reputation to give you a +1.

Comment: @MrEhawk82, Glad I could help.  You can just accept the answer ✓  :-)

Comment: gotcha, slipped my mind.  (i have four kids, so that happens).  On your code: i did change the location of enableFunction(completeBtn);  i put it in the function updateItemStatus().  That way the completeBtn booleon will toggle just like the removeBtn. which is doing exactly what i wanted it to. awesome.

Comment: i also put "&& inputElems[i].checked === true" in the function submitboxes().  That way the complete button will push the selected data.

Comment: This for sure require far more coding. I made just basic functionality (only to save in DB all created boxes as example). If you need to work on boxes that are loaded from DB, then you should determine which boxes were created after the old boxes have been loaded into the "tasks" list. So that you can delete only these which are actually in DB and add to DB new ones in same time. (if I well understand your intention)

Comment: i agree.  i just started on this project.  I think for now, i'm going to work on getting this thing functional on IE & FF before i work on local storage and whatnot.  Works great in Chrome.  I've already added a bunch.  I got the remove button working right, just like the complete button.  Clear all was acting funny but i got that resolved too.  My only real problem is getting everything to work in IE.  I think i'm going to look for a jquery solution. This is going to be my non-published to-do for windows.   Thank you for the help. 1 headache gone, a million to go :)

Comment: question on your fiddle @phillip100 parentNode.remove() works on chrome, but not on IE.  Why is that?